# Getting the Android source-code

Tags: android, android-source, repository

I want to get the Android source code for example for version 2.3_r1 (you can see all version here: http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/)

And according to the http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

I am writing `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3_r1`

But it seems that I am downloading all source code.

What is wrong in my actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not. git is just telling you which branches it has found on the remote side. You will just checkout the branch you specified.

also the whole repo consists of several subrepos - so the `repo` command does multiple `git clone` which also looks like you download all branches. so you will download about 6,5GB and i think about 200 repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's all a single git tree, and specifying the branch like that just says which git branch to checkout after syncing.